# select a number of strings inside a clob

Tags: sql, oracle, clob

sorry I know you expect code examples but I have absolutly no idear how to start with that issue.
I have a database with about 100000 entries of that structure:

```
ID | LONGARG
0    ECLONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS|LONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS|LONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS
     ECLONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS2|LONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS|LONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS
1    ECLONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS|LONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS|LONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS
2    ECLONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS|LONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS|LONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS
     ECLONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS2|LONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS|LONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS
     ECLONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS3|LONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS|LONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS
3    ECLONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS|LONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS|LONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS
     ECLONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS2|LONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS|LONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS
```

Longarg is of type CLOB.

My question is, is there a possibility to select all the text that is between `EC` and the first `|` to get a result like that without using a `StoredProcedure` and for all datarows?

Result:

```
LONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS
LONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS2
LONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS
LONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS
LONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS2
LONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS3
LONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS
LONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS2
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Stefan

Comment: `select id, regexp_substr(longarg, '^EC([^|]*)', 1, 1, '', 1) from table`

Comment: @Egor: please post it as answer.

Comment: and could you tell me how to avoid duplicate entries? distinct does not work

Comment: `select distinct to_char(regexp_substr(longarg, '^EC([^|]*)', 1, 1, '', 1)) from table`.  Sorry, I'm too lazy to write complete answers.

Comment: thx I thought you want some reputation.

Comment: In fact, there is nothing interesting I can spend my reputation points on.  Most programming questions I wanna ask (and give a bounty for an answer) are opinion-based and therefore are not suitable for SO :(